# Removing numbers and _ symbol from a parsed URL using re module and sub() function in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, python-re

I'm trying to exclude "numbers" and the symbols "-" and "_" from a string that I got parsing a URL.

For example,

```
string1 = 'historical-fiction_4'
string_cleaned = re.sub("[^a-z]", "", string1)
print(string1)
print(string_cleaned)

historical-fiction_4
historicalfiction
```

With `re.sub("[^a-z]")` I got just the strings from a to z but instead of getting the string "historicalfiction" I would like to get "Historical Fiction".

More or less all my data is collected with this structure "name1-name2_number".

If anyone can help me improve my re.sub() call I'll really appreciate. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str.title()` to capitalize every word:

```
import re

string1 = "historical-fiction_4"

string1 = re.sub(r"[^a-z]", " ", string1).strip().title()
print(string1)
```

Prints:

```
Historical Fiction
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears to me that your logic is that you want to replace dashes with spaces, but completely strip off underscore and digits.  If so, then use two separate calls to replace:

```py
inp = "historical-fiction_4"
output = re.sub(r'[0-9_]+', '', inp.replace("-", " "))
print(output)  # historical fiction
```

Comment: Thanks a lot both @AndrejKesely and Tim, I combined your answers to get what I needed. Thanks so much for the help.